# laravel blade: how to pass script variable in the markup

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a laravel project, I wann use the script variable test as a parmeter in the markup to call a function, can you please help me to figure it ou? MANY THANKS!
here is the markup:

```
<div id=terminate-note-form>
      <x-input class="w-full format-datepicker date_picker_icon format-datepicker-terminate-note" name="end_date" id="end_date"
      x-init="formatDatepickerTermination(ter_date)" /></div>
```

here is the script:

```
 <script>
function terminateNote(date) {
        ter_date = date;
        $('#terminate-note-form').modal();
    }

function formatDatepickerFilter(date) {
            
        flatpickr(".format-datepicker-filter-note", {
            altInput: true,
            altFormat: 'Y-m-d',
            dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
            allowInput: false,
            minDate: date,
            onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                if (instance.element && instance.element._x_model) {
                    instance.element._x_model.set(dateStr);
                }
            },
            onClose: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                if (instance.element && instance.element._x_model) {
                    instance.element._x_model.set(dateStr);
                }
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: do you mean passing the script variable to blade ?

from where this test variable is coming ?

Comment: @KhayamKhan hi, I just updated my code in the main body, I have a terminateNote function, every time I clicked a btn I will call the function and pass a date as ter-date, I wanna use ter_date as the minDate for the flatpickr

Comment: is this alpine.js? if so can you please add the tag for it

Comment: Why not utilize a blade template that has the script rendered in the footer, why pass it?